# AngularJS - Calling values in response with Spring GET

Tags: angularjs, spring

New here so my description might be bad but I'm trying to access the values on the second level of my JSON but I can't seem to get it. It only brings the values of the top level.

My JSON body looks like the following:

```
{
"services": [
    {
        "nameLevel1": "Example1",
        "secondServices": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "namelevel2": "Example2",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

And when I call it, I only can get the nameLevel1 and that is it. My GET method is this:

```
    $scope.retrieveServices = function (id) {
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {
            "collection": "user",
            "resource": id
        },
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            $scope.userServices = response.services;
            $scope.recievedValues = true;
        }
    );
};
```

Now I originally thought all I would have to do is:

```
    $scope.userServices = response.services.secondServices;
```

But I'm getting an undefined issue. So my query is how do I access all of them? My JSON body when doing a log output does show everything, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to show everything in my table. Only the nameLevel1 values.

Any help would be appreciate, and I hope my description is okay. Edits would be get as well since not too sure if I have labelled this correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get subservices? Your json doesn't have this property

Comment: Sorry, secondServices, let me fix it.

Comment: I would first check the data that comes back from the service in chrome dev console. Make sure your service is returning the expected json.

Comment: It returns everything but I can't seem to output on the GUI.

Comment: add console.log to your service and print out the response. You should see json (that you browser console can parse) not text. Try adding `headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }` to your request.